# How do I fetch the list of received SMS messages from within an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How do I programmatically retrieve all received SMS messages on an iOS device, so that I can display them in a list (such as a table view)?

Comment: You can accept an answer already.

Answer (score 9):

Without being jailbroken you cannot access the SMS database.

However, if you are writing the app to work specifically on a jailbroken device, you can check out the SMS database in the `/Users/Library/`; then access it as you would any other sqlite database.